# .Net 4 equivalent of Thread Dump of Java

Tags: c#-4.0, memory-dump

Is there are Thread dump equivalent for .Net4. We tried using MSE from Microsoft but this does not recognize applications compiled for .Net4.0

Comment: You might find something useful in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.aspx

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to recompile MSE with .NET 4.0. Easy to do using  [Vadim Skipin's project on github](https://github.com/vadimskipin/MSE)  . Good luck.